# aling image with anchor text?

Tags: asp.net, css, listview

I am listview and  to display data. so thought of displaying icon front of

So i did try to use below section.

```
.listview a
{
    font-weight: normal;
    background:transparent url(../images/arrow.png) scroll  no-repeat left center;
    padding:2px 0px 2px 20px;
}
```

it works fine for but if the text goes next line then the second line align to left most which looks odd. ( In stackoverflow you can see the example on right side, "Simliar quuestion" :-)). The next line align to first line if it continue of first line.

Any idea how to handle text for this.

And my listview layout is like below

```
<ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <a href="">
                    <%#Eval("Description")%></a>
           </td>
       </tr>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Should i use `<ul></ul>` instead of `<a></a>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` tag is by default an inline tag, which means top and bottom padding wont work. To fix this you should add `display:block;` to a tag and play around the padding and/or background-position; to set it right.

Comment: Yes, it does align the text the way i want and i had to alter the position too. " background:transparent url(../images/icon.png) scroll  no-repeat 0px 5px;"

Answer (score 0):

You can use two `divs` for that and set the `float` of that. It will work.

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
      <td>
          <a href="">
             <div class="imagBack"></div>
              <div class="noBackImage">
                 <%#Eval("Description")%></a>
              </div>
       </td>
   </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

create style sheet as follows

```
.listview a
{
    display:block
}
.listview a div.imagBack
{
    width:50px;
    float:left;
    font-weight: normal;
    background:transparent url(../images/arrow.png) scroll  no-repeat left center;
    padding:2px 0px 2px 20px;
 }
 .listview a div
 {
    width:100px;
    float:right;
    font-weight: normal;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks shekhar for the reply but i didn't want to use <Div> as i knew i can do like that but wanted to go ahead with anchor text only. Thanks though but i didn't try your solution.